# How to convert selected date into DAY in the bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, time, datetimepicker

I have used this code with codeigniter, but always gets value as "Thursday", How to solve this?

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txt_dob"><span class="form-data-required" >* </span>Birth Date:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="block_txt_dob">
    <div class='input-group date' id='block_txt_dob'>
      <input type='date' id="block_txt_dob" name="txt_dob" class="form-control" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly value="<?php echo set_value(" txt_dob "); ?>" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" title="view calender" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" ></span></span>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block" id="txt_dob_error" data-block="block_txt_dob"><?php echo form_error("txt_dob"); ?></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    //initialize date time picker
    $("#block_txt_dob").datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false,
    });

    //set current date as default
    var cur_date = new Date();
    var str_cur_date = cur_date.getFullYear() + "-" + (parseInt(cur_date.getMonth()) + 1) + "-" + cur_date.getDate();
    $('#block_txt_dob').val(str_cur_date);

  });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
 $timestamp = strtotime('block_txt_dob');
 $day = date('D', $timestamp);
 var_dump($day);
```